# PHP 'Illegal string offset' in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, foreach

I am getting an assoc array from a MySQL database using PDO.

I want to perform a function on it to trim down the number of words by using the following code:

```
$newsContent = Words::truncateWords($rows);
```

I am getting this error and the the function hasn't worked

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in C:\www\mvc\libs\Words.php on line
>   14
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\www\mvc\libs\Words.php on
>   line 14
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in C:\www\mvc\libs\Words.php
>   on line 14

The first error is repeated about 8 times.  Line 14 points to this line

```
$rows[$key]['content'] = self::trunc($row['content'], 60);
```

Here is my Words class

```
class Words {

    // truncate each of the news item's content to a set number of words
    public static function truncateWords($rows) {

        // loop through the array 
        foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
            // and truncate content to 60 words
            $rows[$key]['content'] = self::trunc($row['content'], 60);
        }

        return $rows;
    }

    public function trunc($phrase, $max_words)
    {
        $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);

        if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
            $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, 0, $max_words)).'...';

        return $phrase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because content is not a subscript of `$row` Check first and see if it is.

[`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) checks if the variable is set, but it does not check that variable is NOT null

```
if(array_key_exists('content', $row) {
   self::trunc($row['content'], 60);
}
```

To check that the subscript exists and is not null, use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset)

Comment: Good advice, or try isset (often faster)